# Safari Zero height SVG path not trigger mouse event

Tags: javascript, html, svg, safari

SVG PATH with 2 vertices with no stroke, have the same y coordinates is not responding to mouseevent in Safari only.

Notice that the y-coordinates of the endpoint vertices are the same:

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="ui-interactable-content" style="transform: scale(1); width: 100%; height: 100%;"><svg class="path-selection-svg">
        <path class="path-selection-svg-path" d="M 4 4 L 92.99999999999994 4"></path>
        <path class="path-selection-svg-shape" d="M 4 4 L 92.99999999999994 4"></path>
        </svg>
    </section>
</div>
```

The effect is reproduced here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mf6ueqef/

This works fine in chrome, IE, FF.

Any one know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
Looks like Safari does not respond to pointer events when a path has end points' y-coordinates to be the same, and that the stroke is none.

The fix is simple:
Simply make the stroke non-none

```
stroke: rgba(255,0,0,0.01);
```